# Math.Round issue with 3.75

Tags: .net, rounding

How can I make Math.Round round 3.75 to 3.7?

I've tried the following options:

```
Math.Round(3,75d,1,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) == 3.8
Math.Round(3,75d,1,MidpointRounding.ToEven) == 3.8
```

Edit:
Some context. I need the average of 3.6, 3.5, 4.2, and 3.7, but the requirement is that it should be 3.7 over 3.8.

Comment: try Math.floor instead

Comment: I also recommend using `decimal` for this stuff. Your specific case works with `double` because 0.75 is 3/4. But a number like `x.15` can't be represented as double.

Comment: What about -3.75 or -3.76?

Comment: It's part of a larger measurement, where I need 15d / 4 == 3.7. It must be possible to make it round down?

Comment: Can you provide some additional context? Some other cases? Are you always, for example, dividing by 4 here? Would it just make sense to put the constant 3.7 in here?

Comment: `return 3.7` meets what you told us about your requirements, but that's certainly not what you want. You need to clarify your problem, but telling us what the following inputs should return: `-3.75`, `-3.76`, `3.76`, `3.85`

Comment: What "requirement" says this? Is the goal to simulate `ToOdd` or `ToZero` rounding? Because the requirement rules *must* be unified over some/the number range to be useful. *Explain how the rounding should work for an arbitrary number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can specify decimal precision with `Math.Floor`. But you could try:

```
Math.Floor(num * 10) / 10
```

I believe `Math.Floor` returns a double. So this should work.

Comment: `Floor` should be capitalized.

Comment: Math.Floor, just provides me with 3.0?

Comment: @MadsTjørnelundToustrup Not if you use the code JRSmith posted. First multiplying by 10 and then dividing by 10 after truncation solves that part. But if you don't answer my question and Bob's questions we can't tell you if that actually solves your problem.

Comment: That's what I get for not proofreading my pseudocode. Good catch Reed.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 3.75;
a = System.Math.Round (n, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven);       // 3.70
b = System.Math.Round (n, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // 3.80
```

also try `Math.Floor`

use `a` for your work!

Comment: Its important that I only have a single decimal.

Comment: @RuneFS And then? 3.75 will still become 3.8

Answer (score 0):

So, rather than the *conventional* rule of =x.5 = x+1 ie. 1.04 rounds to 1.0 and 1.05 rounds to 1.1. You want to always go down?

You can do this with Floor (as shown in previous replies) but I think this'll give problems with negative numbers - you'll have to do a bit of testing (so you need to use a 'if' clause to use ceiling instead if your number is <0.